# Django: Redirecting a user after successful Twitter login

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, redirect, twitter

I'm building an application wherein users can login into my site using their Twitter account. On successful login, I want users to be redirected to the homepage. Initially, the Callback URL in my application settings was `http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/twitter/callback`, which redirected users to the following webpage on successful login:

[image]

Now, since I wanted users to get redirected back to the homepage, I changed the value of Callback URL in my application settings to: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. However, this change made no difference and users still get redirected to the above webpage which says `Session expired.`

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rango',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'socialregistration',
    'socialregistration.contrib.twitter'
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 'django.core.context_processors.debug', 'django.core.context_processors.i18n', 'django.core.context_processors.media', 'django.core.context_processors.static', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages', 'django.core.context_processors.request',) 

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        'socialregistration.contrib.twitter.auth.TwitterAuth',
)

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY = ''

SITE_ID = 1

SESSION_SERIALIZER='django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'GetEvangelized.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
    url(r'^social/', include('socialregistration.urls',
                namespace = 'socialregistration')))
```

How can I redirect my users to the homepage and display a custom message after a successful Twitter login?

PS: I'm using `django-socialregistration` for implementing Twitter login.

EDIT 1:

I changed my Callback URL value to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango` based on the suggestions of a comment. However, I'm still redirected back to the above webpage with the same message.

Comment: Manas for this http://127.0.0.1:8000/ there is no handler in your urls.py              example (r'^', include(v1_api.urls))

Comment: Why you didn't have the callback view and success upon redirect to home URL ?

Comment: @RajaSimon How do I implement that? Sorry if that's a silly question, I'm new to Django and still figuring out how things work.

Comment: @AvinashGarg I'm edited my code based on your suggestions. However, I'm still encountering the same error.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi Which django version you are using ?

Comment: @RajaSimon Django 1.7.1

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi try adding `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'` in settings.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81613/discussion-between-manas-chaturvedi-and-raja-simon).